# Will Mac Mini work with Dell Inspiron Laptop

Tags: mac, mac-mini

I am interested in buying the new Mac Mini as I cannot afford a Mac book or Air. The laptop I have is Dell Inspiron 3537. So I wanted to know is it possible to connect Mac Mini with my Dell laptop.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect them?

Comment: Connect in what way? You can add them to the same Network, but little else.

Comment: The thing is I need to do some development work on Yosemite. And since I cannot afford Mac Book, I was suggested that I should go for Mac Mini which you can connect to any laptop(in my case Dell 3537) and you can then use it as a Mac Book.I hope this makes sense. Sorry,I am new to Apple products that's why I asked this question.

Comment: You could use VNC to connect to it from your Dell laptop, but you will have to connect a keyboard, mouse and monitor to it to set that up initially.

Answer (score 1):

## VNC

You can use [VNC on your Mac](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/vnc/) to show the screen on your Windows or Linux laptop:

> **VNC is an abbreviation of Virtual Network Computing**. VNC is a common protocol that allows computers to both share and to offer control over the network. Using VNC you can connect to and see your computer remotely; great for remote working or helping a relative perform tricky tasks without needing to be in the same location.
>
> **Mac OS X includes a built-in free VNC server**. You can set up and use VNC on your Mac without needing additional or third party software.

There are numerous Windows and Linux [VNC clients](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+vnc+viewer) you can use on your Dell laptop.

Also see answers to these related questions:

- [Is it possible to use a Mac Mini with a laptop monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241802/is-it-possible-to-using-mac-mini-with-laptop-monitor)
- [Use Dell Inspiron laptop monitor as only monitor for mac mini](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23917/use-dell-inspiron-laptop-monitor-as-only-monitor-for-mac-mini)