# Is it possible to use a Mac Mini with a laptop monitor?

Tags: mac, display, mac-mini

I want to buy a Mac Mini and I want to use it with my laptop monitor. My laptop is Lenovo Y510P. I searched some documents for using Mac Mini with laptop monitor and I only found a solution to using with an Apple laptop unfortunately.

My laptop doesn't have a video input but can I use the Mac Mini via an external video capture devices etc? Or is there a way to use Mac Mini with laptop monitor?

Answer (score 3):

## VNC

You can use [VNC on your Mac Mini](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/vnc/) to show the screen on your Windows or Linux laptop:

> **VNC is an abbreviation of Virtual Network Computing**. VNC is a common protocol that allows computers to both share and to offer control over the network. Using VNC you can connect to and see your computer remotely; great for remote working or helping a relative perform tricky tasks without needing to be in the same location.
>
> **Mac OS X includes a built-in free VNC server**. You can set up and use VNC on your Mac without needing additional or third party software.

There are numerous Windows and Linux [VNC clients](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+vnc+viewer) you can use on your Lenovo laptop.

Also see answers to these related questions:

- [Is it possible to use a Mac Mini with a laptop monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241802/is-it-possible-to-using-mac-mini-with-laptop-monitor)
- [Use Dell Inspiron laptop monitor as only monitor for mac mini](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23917/use-dell-inspiron-laptop-monitor-as-only-monitor-for-mac-mini)

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson please can you [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).